Le Chatelier's principle with concept of limiting reactant
I think that the concept of limiting reactant must be added to further clarify the concept of Le Chatelier's principle . Consider a reaction at equilibrium , if we Increase the concentration of reactant "A" we must increase the concentration of reactant "B" otherwise A is in excess and no B is available to react with A to produce "C" and "D".
Am i right or not?

The concept of limiting reactant is "limited" to reactions which go to completion and are not at equilibrium.

You are wrong.
Reaction's product concentrations at equilibrium are going to change to another different equilibrium concentration. The fact that B is still available, is the reason why we need to consider equilibrium in the first place.
The excess of "A" helps unreacted "B" species to more often form a product, whereas it doesn't change the rate at which any given product molecule decays back to the reactants again.
